# Entering a proper path to files on DBFS

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition

I uploaded files to DBFS:

> /FileStore/shared_uploads/name_surname@xxx.xxx/file_name.csv

I tried to access them by pandas and I always receive information that such files don't exist.
I tried to use the following paths:

```
/dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/name_surname@xxx.xxx/file_name.csv
dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/name_surname@xxx.xxx/file_name.csv
dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/name_surname@xxx.xxx/file_name.csv
./FileStore/shared_uploads/name_surname@xxx.xxx/file_name.csv
```

What is funny, when I check them by dbutils.fs.ls I see all the files.

I found this solution, and I tried it already: [Databricks dbfs file read issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784646/databricks-dbfs-file-read-issue)

Moved them to a new folder:

```
dbfs:/new_folder/
```

I tried to access them from this folder, but still, it didn't work for me. The only difference is that I copied files to a different place.

I checked as well the documentation: https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html

I use Databricks Community Edition.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and why it's happening like that.
I don't have any other ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/dbfs/` mount point isn't available on the Community Edition (that's a known limitation), so you need to do what is recommended in the linked answer:

```py
dbutils.fs.cp(
  'dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/name_surname@xxx.xxx/file_name.csv', 
  'file:/tmp/file_name.csv')
```

and then use `/tmp/file_name.csv` as input parameter to Pandas' functions. If you'll need to write something to DBFS, then you do other way around - write to local file `/tmp/...`, and copy that file to DBFS.

Comment: Thanks, I'm quite new to Databricks. It started to work when I referred to it in the following way: `file:/tmp/fine_name.csv`