# Unable to access files uploaded to dbfs on Databricks community edition Runtime 9.1. Tried the dbutils.fs.cp workaround which also didn't work

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I'm a beginner to Spark and just picked up the highly recommended 'Spark - the Definitive Edition' textbook. Running the code examples and came across the first example that needed me to upload the flight-data csv files provided with the book. I've uploaded the files at the following location as shown in the screenshot:

`/FileStore/tables/spark_the_definitive_guide/data/flight-data/csv`

[image]

I've in the past used Azure Databricks to upload files directly onto DBFS and access them using `ls` command without any issues. But now in community edition of Databricks (Runtime 9.1) I don't seem to be able to do so.

When I try to access the csv files I just uploaded into dbfs using the below command:

`%sh ls /dbfs/FileStore/tables/spark_the_definitive_guide/data/flight-data/csv`

I keep getting the below error:

`ls: cannot access '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/spark_the_definitive_guide/data/flight-data/csv': No such file or directory`

I tried finding out a solution and came across the suggested workaround of using `dbutils.fs.cp()` as below:

`dbutils.fs.cp('C:/Users/myusername/Documents/Spark_the_definitive_guide/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide-master/data/flight-data/csv', 'dbfs:/FileStore/tables/spark_the_definitive_guide/data/flight-data/csv')`

`dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/spark_the_definitive_guide/data/flight-data/csv/', 'C:/Users/myusername/Documents/Spark_the_definitive_guide/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide-master/data/flight-data/csv/', recurse=True)`

Neither of them worked. Both threw the error:  `java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: C`

This is really blocking me from proceeding with my learning. It would be supercool if someone can help me solve this soon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entering a proper path to files on DBFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69594933/entering-a-proper-path-to-files-on-dbfs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way you are trying to use is the wrong one, use it like this

to list the data:

display(dbutils.fs.ls("/FileStore/tables/spark_the_definitive_guide/data/flight-data/"))

to copy between databricks directories:

dbutils.fs.cp("/FileStore/jars/d004b203_4168_406a_89fc_50b7897b4aa6/databricksutils-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl","/FileStore/tables/new.whl")

For local copy you need the premium version where you create a token and configure the databricks-cli to send from the computer to the dbfs of your databricks account:

databricks fs cp C:/folder/file.csv dbfs:/FileStore/folder