# run dll files on notebook pySpark

Tags: pyspark, dll, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I want to run dll file based on C# code into my pySpark notebook (in databricks) using 'clr' method. Unfortunately I can't figure out what should be my 'Assembly Name/ .NET reference'. The file is in correct location and there is no typo when I try to use C# 'Namespace.Class.Function' or direct location to the file (I've been trying multiple ways but still same problem).

Here is my approach:

```
!pip install pythonnet

%sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mono-complete

%sh
echo '#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mono-complete' > conf/install_mono.sh
```

```
import os
import clr
import sys

# Set environment variables
os.environ["PYTHONNET_PYDLL"] = "dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/ptgkahoot@gmail.com/SampleClassLibraryProject.dll"

# Add a reference to your .NET assembly
clr.AddReference("SampleClassLibraryProject") #Here is the problem!!!

# Set the .NET runtime based on environment variables
sys.path.append("/Users/admin/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages")  # Replace with your Python home path

# Now try importing the necessary module
from SampleClassLibraryProject.Algebra import Addition  # Import specific namespace and class

# Example usage:
result = Addition.Add(2, 3)
print(result)
```

Error message :[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB2Cy.png)
File path location: [File path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD734.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dbfs:/` use `/dbfs/` as a prefix for the file path - the reason for that .Net doesn't understand the DBFS file system URL, and needs the local file path.

Update: on Community Edition, the DBFS fuse isn't available (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69594933/entering-a-proper-path-to-files-on-dbfs/69595446#69595446)), so you need to use `dbutils.fs.cp` to copy file from DBFS to the local disk, and then point to that copy, like this:

```py
local_file = 'file:/tmp/SampleClassLibraryProject.dll'
dbutils.fs.cp(
  'dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/ptgkahoot@gmail.com/SampleClassLibraryProject.dll', 
  local_file)
os.environ["PYTHONNET_PYDLL"] = local_file
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: What Databricks are you using? Community edition?

Comment: Yes, I do use Community edition!

Comment: I've updated my answer, adopted for CE