# gdal cannot read raster file in dbfs

Tags: databricks, gdal

I'm trying a simple code to read a tif file using gdal in databricks but the output is NoneType. Is it dfbs limitation?

```
from osgeo import gdal

filepath = "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/myraster.tif"
raster = gdal.Open(filepath)
```

I get the below error:

```
RuntimeError: dbfs:/FileStore/tables/myraster.tif: No such file or directory
```

I have tested the file reading it as image and it works fine:

```
dfRaw = spark.read.format("image").load(filepath)
```

Answer (score 1):

because gdal uses Python file API, it can't work with `dbfs:/` URLs. Instead you need to replace `dbfs:` with `/dbfs` if you're on full Databricks workspace:

```
from osgeo import gdal

filepath = "/dbfs/FileStore/tables/myraster.tif"
raster = gdal.Open(filepath)
```

Or use `dbutils.fs.cp` on Community Edition (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66784646/databricks-dbfs-file-read-issue/66835075#66835075))